# What value is stored in an initialized but empty integer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, null, initialization, zero

I made the following array:

```
int[] array = new int[9];
```

This array is initialized, but empty.

In that case, what is the value of any index of this array?

When I print it out, it gives me 0.
Does that mean there is a zero stored in here (like if you had called `int x = 0`)?
Or is it `null`?

Also, is this the same for any `Object` array?
Is it an empty instance of this object, or is it `null`?

Comment: all 1s. This is basic Java in any 101 book or tutorial. Have you seen the ones on Oracle? http://goo.gl/QiHpsb

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be trivially found in the documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @JeroenVannevel are general purpose questions not allowed on SnackOverflow; if so, how would we flag them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default initialization of an array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java)

Comment: The array is not 'empty', it is full with 9 instances of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an Array of objects it will be initialized with `null`, if it's an array of primitive values (like `int`) it will be initialized with `0`. For the non-number primitive `boolean` it is `false` and for 'char' it is `'\u0000'`. For more information, check the table Default Values on the following page:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: and if the primitive is `boolean`, it'll be initialized with `false` value.

Comment: @MelikaBarzegaranHosseini I've edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

A copy from [Oracle Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

[Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) - Default Values:

```
Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
byte        0
short       0
int         0
long        0L
float       0.0f
double      0.0d
char        '\u0000'
String      null
Object      null
boolean     false
```

So, for int, it is zero (0).

Answer (score 0):

All elements are initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Integer class can be null however "int" type cannot be null.

You can try int x = null; you'll have an error.

Therefore it is created by default to 0 until you change it.

Answer (score 0):

Every value in an int array is initialized to 0 by default. This is something that you can easily try on your own:

```
    int [] nums = new int [9];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(nums[i]);
    }
```

Result:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the default values for the different types in Java:

byte    0

short   0

int     0

long    0L

float   0.0f

double  0.0d

char    ‘u0000′

String (or any Object)  null

boolean false

As you can see, int defaults to 0.