# Java: How can i remove null value from a string?

Tags: java, string, null

When this code is run, it outputs `nullhi`. Why is it doing this?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = new String[1];
    String m = null;
    String c = "hi";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length() ; i++){
        a[0] = a[0] + c.charAt(i);  
    }
    System.out.print(a[0]);
}
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Before the loop, write:

```
a[0] = "";
```

i.e.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] a= new String[1];
String m = null;
String c = "hi";

a[0] = "";

for (int i=0 ; i<c.length() ; i++){
    a[0]=a[0]+c.charAt(i);  
}

System.out.print(a[0]);

}
```

Comment: @Angelb - In addition, the variable `a` does not need to be an array. You may have heard that Java Strings are immutable. This is true. However, in the expression `String a = ""`, the variable `a` is not a String -- it is a mutable reference to a String.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
    for (int i=0 ; i<c.length() ; i++){
      a[i] = "";
      a[i]= c.charAt(i);  

    }
```

what you are doing is

```
for (int i=0 ; i<c.length() ; i++){
    a[0]=a[0]+c.charAt(i);  // a[0] is null, 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Test if string is null

```
a[0] = ((a[0] == null) ? "" : a[0] ) + c.charAt(i);
```

Comment: `a[0]` will always be `null` until it is explicitly changed. That is how object arrays are initialized.

Comment: Whats going on here? This solution removes the null in the output because a[0] is checked on null. Learn programming before downvoting correct answers

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but why not just have `a[0] = "";` before the loop instead of checking it every time?

Comment: Both correct and not the question. All fine, only understand sometimes not the reactions of people here. I think twice before I don't vote something.