# JLabel array nullpointerexception

Tags: java, arrays, jlabel

Maybe I'm just being blind or having a bad moment but for the life of me I can't manage to get this to work! It keeps throwing a null pointer exception.

Edit: The array's are initialised with normal string values, I've just not pasted it here.

```
ArrayList<String> starttime = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> endtime = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Integer> bay = new ArrayList();

JLabel[] startTimes = new JLabel[starttime.size()-1];
JLabel[] endTimes = new JLabel[endtime.size()-1];
JLabel[] bayNo = new JLabel[bay.size()-1];

for (int i  = 0; i < starttime.size(); i++) {
    startTimes[i].setText("1");
    endTimes[i].setText("1");
    bayNo[i].setText("1");
    choices.add(startTimes[i]);
    choices.add(endTimes[i]);
    choices.add(bayNo[i]);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only create an array, but don't initialize the values in it.
Create the labels in the array and everything should work.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < starttime.size() ; i++){
    startTimes[i] = new JLable("1");
    ...
}
```