# Array Index assignment error with UserInput as If-Else conditional

Tags: java, arrays, assignment-operator

I am getting an error and I cant quite understand the cause. I'm trying to get user-input using the **Scanner** method to assign values to the indices of an array, *numbers*. The user is allowed to keep - continue - entering values into the array *numbers*, however, if the user decides to stop, entering **0** will break the assignment of array-index values.

```
    int[] numbers = new int[100];
    int[] countIndex = new int[100];
    int[] numberOcc = new int[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < countIndex.length; i++)
    {
        countIndex[i] = i;
    }

    System.out.println("Enter your integer values: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {

        if(input.nextInt() == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

This piece of code is a small part of a much larger code, however, it is very important. ***The error***  I'm getting is that the code is allowing the user to enter twice before moving to the next index, but the first integer entered it always skipped:

```
Enter your integer values: 
1
2
0
0 occurs 99 times
2 occurs 1 time
```

***UPDATES***

```
    System.out.println("Enter your integer values: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        if(numbers[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Why is it that the **1**  is ignored as input?
Also, is using **input.nextInt()** as the condition of an if-else statement bad code design?

Comment: You do have two `input.nextInt()`. I would recommend you to only receive input once and then use `equals()` to compare that to `0` and if not then go to the `else`

Comment: @sam Hm I've considered what you said and it works - somewhat. However, a **0** is still being placed in the index, and I still don't understand why the conditional would cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments

> However, a 0 is still being placed in the index,

[By default, int values will be assigned 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java). So when you don't assign non zero values to int, they will still be 0.

One way around that is to use [`arraylist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Then once you enter all the numbers, you can convert arraylist to array.

Simple example without any input validation

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
int[] defaultArray = new int[n];
// do validation for n
//assume n = 5 with values 1,2,0,3,2
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int temp = in.nextInt();

    if (temp != 0) {
        list.add(temp);
        defaultArray[i] = temp;
    }
}
Integer[] positiveArray = new Integer[list.size()];
positiveArray = list.toArray(positiveArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(defaultArray));  //will print [1, 2, 0, 3, 2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(positiveArray));  //will print [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

If you want to convert Integer arraylist to int array, just search on google and there are many similar questions.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/i2UyDM)

Comment: I know how to do it with an arraylist - it would have made this easier. However, the task at hand is more of a fundamental exercise for writing complex algorithms with just the basics. Funny how the simplest part trumped me. Thanks Sam!

Comment: @LeSunstrike You're welcome. Atleast now you know, why it was displaying `0`. Good luck