# How can i use a constructor using JOptionPane to pass objects from my method into a empty array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out how to store the objects from the constructor. so far all I get is one object and the remaining are all null. If someone can explain it to me so that a beginner can understand that would be much appreciated.

```
public class Bookstore 
{
    /*
    Main Class Bookstore to be made modular 
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        Book catalogue[] = new Book[3];

        int select;
        do
        {
            select = bookMenu();
            switch(select)
            {
            case 1:  
                int i =0;
                if(catalogue[i] != null)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Test");
                    break;
                }
                catalogue[i] = addBook();

            case 2:     
                sortBook();     
            break;
            case 3:     
                searchBook(catalogue);   
            break;
            case 4:     
                displayBook(catalogue);  
            break;
            case 5:
            break;
            }   
        }
        while(select != 5);
    }
    public static int bookMenu()
    {
        int select;
        String menuOptions = "--Book store--\n"
                + "\n1. Add book to catalogue"
                + "\n2.Sort and display books by price"
                + "\n3. Search for a book by title" 
                + "\n4. Display all books"
                + "\n\n5. Exit";
        do
        {
            select = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menuOptions)); 
        }
        while(select < 1 || select > 5);
        return select;  
    }
    public static Book addBook()
    {
        int isbn;
        String title, author;
        Book catalogue = null;
        double price;
        for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
        {   
            isbn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                ("Enter Book ISBN or: "));
            title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                ("Enter Book Title: ");
            author = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                ("Enter Book Author: ");
            price = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                ("Enter Book Price: "));    
            catalogue = new Book(isbn, title, author, price);    
        }
        return catalogue;
    }
    public static void sortBook()
    {

    }
    public static void searchBook(Book catalogue[])//remain void
    {
        String searchValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the title of the book you are searching for");
        boolean found = true;
        for(int i=0; i<catalogue.length && catalogue[i] != null ; i++)          
        {
            if(searchValue.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogue[i].getTitle()))  
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book details: " + catalogue[i].toString()); 
                found = true; 
            }  
        }
        if(found == false)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The title does not exist in the collection ");
    }
    public static void displayBook(Book catalogue[])//remain void
    {
        String output = "";
        for(Book bk:catalogue)
        {
        output += bk + "\n";
        }        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please limit your  posts to only one problem / question

Comment: My apologies, I've revised the question, what I need help with is filling the array with objects from input

Comment: Did you try to make a `private Book[]` member variable?

Comment: And if you want a dynamic list of objects (not a fixed size) , use an Arraylist

Comment: my constructor global variables are private int, string, string, double

Comment: My instructions are to use an array not an array list

Comment: You don't have any constructor here, so I don't know what you're talking about. Also, I'm not referring to the `Book` class. (I assume you have two classes here, `Book.java` and some other java file with this main method)

Comment: I just added the constructor code and it was called Book.java, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is always false...

```
if(count == max)
```

You set the values immediately before that statement. Zero never equals ten.

Some IDEs would even point that out to you.

---

If you want to get a variable that can be used between methods, you need to learn variable scoping.

For example, using a static class variable

```
private static Book[] books;
private static final int  MAX_BOOKS = 10;
private static int count;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    books = getBooks();
    bookMenu();
}

public static Book[] getBooks() {
    if(count == MAX_BOOKS) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Catalogue full - cannot add any more books");
    } else {
        for(; count < MAX_BOOKS; count++) {
            books[count]= addBook();
        }
    } 
    return books;
}
```

---

Then, if you want to repeat the menu, use a loop. Don't place it at the end of every method.

Also `searchBook(Book)` isn't searching for a title. You want to pass a string to the method, not a Book class

Comment: thanks for that, how will I do it without declaring anything globally?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Class variables are "global".

Comment: How do I store objects into the array, the first one is listed but the remaining come up as null I a beginner at Java

Comment: How do I store objects into the array, the first one is listed but the remaining come up as null I a beginner at Java

Comment: You're already storing objects in the Array. All Array elements will be null until you assign them, as explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java