# Strings java anagrams

Tags: java, anagram

```
String str="cat";
char[] arr = new char[26];
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
    arr[str.charAt(i)-'a']++;
}
String ns = new String(arr);
```

I came across this piece of code. My doubt is as the array arr is containing \u0000 by default what is this  incrementing( arr[str.charAt(i)-'a']++;) operation doing. And how can this arr be converted to a string ns with so many null values in between.  sharing the link of full code. The code is running fine.
http://www.programcreek.com/2014/04/leetcode-anagrams-java/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default initialization of an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java)

Comment: It's a hacky compression of a `Map<Character, Integer>` for chars in the range a-z

Answer (score 0):

The code counts the frequencies of characters of the input string into a `char[]`.
Instead of an `int[]`.
Which sounds counter-intuitive.
But this leads to an efficient solution, with some limitations.

The trick is that you can create a `String` fairly efficiently from a `char[]`,
and it will give you the benefits of `String.equals`.
A string created from a `char[]` that contains character frequencies will not be something readable, but that doesn't matter.
Such string will be usable in a hash table,
as the linked code does,
because `String.equals` has an implementation that's suitable to use in hash tables.

By contrast, an `int[]` doesn't have a useful implementation of `equals`.
This is because arrays inherit the implementation of `equals` from `Object`,
which is not very useful.
The consequence of this is that `a.equals(b)` will return `false` when `a != b`, even if they both contain the same values.
Thanks to `String.equals`,
`new String(a).equals(new String(b))` will return `true` when `a` and `b` are `char[]`, `a != b`, but they contain the same values.
Moreover, there is no way to convert a `int[]` to something suitable to use in a hash map that would be faster than `new String(char[])`.

The limitation is that if `str` contains characters that occur more than 65535 times, then the algorithm will not produce correct output.

Comment: have u seen the link i provided . Though it is not converting ns as some readable string but the hashmap is succesfully constructed and u can see by printing the values present in them . that is what i meant by "working fine"

Comment: @beginner you're right, I read the linked page now, and rewrote my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method

```
static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    int aSum = a.toUpperCase().chars().sorted().sum();
    int bSum = b.toUpperCase().chars().sorted().sum();        
    if(aSum == bSum)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```