# Null pointer exception while converting character array to String in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

In my code snippet, I am trying to first generate a `Character` array and then aggregate it into a `String` but I keep hitting a `NullPointerException`. Is there memory not pointed to and being accessed here **or** is there some kind of type mismatch?

**Source code :**

```
private int getRandomDigit() {
    return (random.nextInt(10));
}

private Character getRandomCharacter() {
    return (char) (65 + random.nextInt(26));
}

public void setRandomizedCustomerID() {

    Character[] customerID_ = new Character[10];

    customerID_[0] = Character.forDigit(getRandomDigit(), 10);
    customerID_[1] = Character.forDigit(getRandomDigit(), 10);
    customerID_[2] = getRandomCharacter();
    customerID_[3] = getRandomCharacter();
    customerID_[4] = getRandomCharacter();
    customerID_[5] = getRandomCharacter();
    customerID_[6] = Character.forDigit(getRandomDigit(), 10);
    customerID_[7] = getRandomCharacter();
    customerID_[8] = getRandomCharacter();
    customerID_[9] = Character.forDigit(getRandomDigit(), 10);

    for (Character c : customerID_) 
        customerID += c.toString(); /* customerID is a field of type String */
}
```

**main method :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenerateRecords[] recordArray = new GenerateRecords[1000];
    String[] recordsToBeWritten = new String[1000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        recordArray[i].setRandomizedCustomerID(); /* NullPointerException thrown here */
        recordArray[i].setRandomizedOccupationID();
        recordArray[i].setRandomizedIncome();
        recordArray[i].setRandomizedDebt();
        recordsToBeWritten[i] = recordArray[i].getRandomizedCustomerID() + "," + recordArray[i].getRandomizedState()
                + "," + recordArray[i].getRandomizedGender() + "," + recordArray[i].getRandomizedAge() + ","
                + recordArray[i].getRandomizedRace() + "," + recordArray[i].getRandomizedMaritalStatus() + ","
                + recordArray[i].getRandomizedOccupation() + "," + recordArray[i].getRandomizedIncome() + ","
                + recordArray[i].getRandomizedDebt() + "," + recordArray[i].getRandomizedLoanType() + "," + "?";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        System.out.println(recordsToBeWritten[i] + "\n");
}
```

Comment: `GenerateRecords[] recordArray = new GenerateRecords[1000];` only creates array *for* GenerateRecords objects, but it doesn't fill it with such objects (it doesn't decide for you which `GenerateRecords` constructor to use or what parameters should be passed). Instead that array is filled with nulls. So before you will be able to use `recordArray[i].setRandomizedCustomerID();` you need to assign `recordArray[i] = new GenerateRecords(yourArguments);`. Duplicate also explains it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23852556/1393766

Comment: Yes I know it throws the same exception as NullPointerException as the page I have supposedly duplicated but NullPointerException could arise in different scenarios. @Pshemo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java

Comment: "but NullPointerException could arise in different scenarios" yes, but your question is about specific scenario which is described by your code. I tried explain your specific problem in my first comment. If you are interested in other potential scenarios where NPE can be thrown then it is already answered in duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep in mind not to duplicate questions.