# Does array skips empty position while showing result?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I tried to create Floyd's triangle, that looks like this.

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

but while practicing I mistyped and created a different kind triangle by using this code,

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value=1;
        int[][] arr = new int[4][4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {

                if( i<=j ){
                    System.out.print(value+" ");
                    value++;
                }
            }System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

and it printed this,

```
1 2 3 4                                                                                                                                        
5 6 7                                                                                                                                          
8 9                                                                                                                                            
10
```

Now my question is that while reading about arrays, I read that the particular value at the particular position gets printed.

So if that is true, then ouput of this code should be like,

```
[1][2][3][4]
[x][5][6][7]
[x][x][8][9]
[x][x][x][10]
```

Does array skip these empty fields while showing the result?
Please help to understand this

Comment: 1. your code does not use arrays 2. there is no such thing as empty field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these values are not being skipped by the array.

They are skipped because you wrote code to skip them in the form of this condition:

```
      if( i<=j ){
          System.out.print(value+" ");
          value++;
      }
```

If you remove the condition, all 16 values will be printed.

Comment: Because text is always printed left to right. The terminal doesn't know that you are looping over an array and can't try to align the text, it can only shows what you put in print/println statements

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's a mistake in the condition. It should be the opposite one:

```
            if( j <= i ){
                System.out.print(value+" ");
                value++;
            }
```

I guess it'd be easier if you stopped using artificial *i*s and *j*s and started using *row* and *column*.

However, please note that in Java you're not creating two-dimensional arrays, but an array of arrays, which can be any size at any dimension.

PS. You're not using the array in inner loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It would print the 0's as 0's because when an array is initialized all values are set to zero and if you print they will print like that. Here's a link

[What is the default initialization of an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

No, as @that other guy said, it is the if condition which is skipping.
Try this program -

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int value=1;
        int[][] arr = new int[4][4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {

                if( i<=j ){
                    System.out.print(value+" ");
                    System.out.print("\t");
                    value++;
                } else {
                    System.out.print(0);
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
            }System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

This printed -

1   2   3   4
0   5   6   7
0   0   8   9
0   0   0   10

NOTE - There is no use of arr in the program.