# Interface array in java

Tags: java

### why is this line valid in java

I have just copied a line of the program , if you could explain it to me. Thanks

```
Runnable r[] = new Runnable[5];
```

Comment: we can't create objects for interfaces , iam confuse on these line

Comment: But you _can_ make **classes** that _implement_ the `Runnable` interface, and you can make objects of those classes.  Objects of classes that implement `Runnable` are what you you would store in this array.

Comment: `Runnable[]` isn't an object of `Runnable`, it's a container that holds `Runnable` objects.

Comment: [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1-200-A]#jls-10.1-200-A[/url) allows it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Runnable[5]` creates an **array** of `Runnable` type. It does not instantiate `Runnable`.

The invalid code would be the one caling `new Runnable()`. In other words, what is not allowed is the direct instantiation of an interface type, but you could create an array whose type is an interface.

Answer (score 1):

By delaring a `Runable` array,  you are not creating any object of the `Runable` interface, but **an object of a certain java array class**. So the compiler will not give any error. You are just declaring an array in which the elements must be objects of certain classes, which implements the `Runable` interface.

From JLS:

> Every array has an associated Class object, shared with all other arrays with the same component type. [This] acts as if: the direct superclass of an array type is Object [and] every array type implements the interfaces Cloneable and java.io.Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing any of the elements with this line, so you haven't implemented the interface. You don't need to at this point, you are allocating space for the array of type interface. Later in the program, the elements are likely initialized and when they are they are done with implementations of the interface and not the interface itself.

Answer (score 1):

It’s **only** an array of references, and the initialization is not complete until the reference itself is initialized by creating a new `Runnable` object.

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426854/1465553) clearly states :

> For references (anything that holds an object) that is **null**.

and you can always write:

```
interface Foo{}

Foo foo = null;
```