# What does this code tell computer to do lights[k] = !lights[k];?

Tags: java, arrays

what does this code tells the computer to do?
P.s. The 'lights' is a boolean array.

```
for (int k = 1; k < lights.length; k++)
                lights[k] = !lights[k];
```

Comment: I highly recommend that you learn to use a debugger. This tool will allow you to step through your code and let you  see what is happening on each line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's basically toggling the boolean flags in the array (except the first one). A `true` flag will be set to `false` and vice-versa.

Note that any uninitialized items of a `boolean` array will be `false` in Java.

```js
const lights = [false, false, false];

//toggling flags except the first one
for (let k = 1; k < lights.length; k++)
    lights[k] = !lights[k];
    
console.log(lights);
```

Comment: But in the code I have the items of the lights array have not been set to True or false, that has been just initialized. So are all the arrays items true or false by default somehow?

Comment: This looks like JavaScript, not Java like the question is tagged.

Comment: @AltinMullaidrizi Could you show how the array initialization code looks like?

Comment: @plalx Here it is:  boolean[] lights = new boolean[101];

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java) all items (but the first one, given index starts at 1) would initialize to `false` and running the loop would set them all `true`.

Comment: @AltinMullaidrizi When you instantiate an array in Java the entries in the array are set to zero for a numeric type, false for boolean, or null for reference types, so your array will be filled with false when you first create it.

Comment: @plalx Running the loop would not set them all to true. The loop does not affect the item at `lights[0]`.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yeah, had already stated that in the answer and you were quick on the comment because I changed mine like 5 seconds after posting to point that out hehe.

Comment: Thanks! Now I completely understand how this code that first looked complex, works!