# Is it possible to do this in Java?

Tags: java, python

This is the python 2.7 code and its output

```
i = [0 for i in range(5)]
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

what is the closest code to do this in Java?

Comment: `int[] i = new int[5]` definitely;

Comment: There are no list comprehensions in Java.  In this particular case, `Collections.nCopies(5, 0)`.

Comment: Smart use of default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the closest code:

````
public class Stackoverflow_03262019 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr=new int[5];
        Arrays.fill(arr,0);
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(val-> System.out.println(val));
    }
}
```
You can add any value instead of 0;
````

Comment: Just a note the arrays do not need to be filled with 0's. The array in Java will be set to the values default value, numbers = 0, bools = false and objects = null. [SO - Default Array Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Actually only the int[] arr=new int[5]; would solve it since 0 is the default.