# Why don't we need to initialise instance variables

Tags: java, instance-variables

I'm relatively inexperienced with java and so I was doing a little bit of testing. I came across the following behaviour which seemed odd to me.

Take the following class:

```
public class FooBar {
  int foo;
  public void bar() {
    foo = foo + 1;
  }
}
```

The above code compiles and works. When running `bar()` once, `foo` is set to `1`. This was surprising to me as I expected an error because when running `bar()` for the first time `foo` is not initialised, and so I would've thought an error would've occurred.

Naturally, I thought that if something like this works, then I would've also expected something like this to compile and run:

```
public class FooBar {
  public int bar() {
    int foo;
    foo = foo + 1; // Err: The local variable foo may not have been initialized
    return foo;
  }
}
```

However, when trying to compile this code I get an error:

> The local variable foo may not have been initialized

**My question:** Why does the first example of the class `FooBar` compile and run as expected, but the second doesn't?

Comment: Instance fields have default values, objects to null.  Local variables don't have defaults.  Numbers default to 0.

Comment: Instance variables have defaults. In this case, zero. Locals don't. A stupid inconsistency of the language if you ask me but it is what it is.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That explains a lot.

Comment: @Michael The performance loss if they didn't do it that way would be even more stupid. It's a normal design decision, and not exclusive to Java.

Comment: perhaps, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426854

Comment: @user207421 It's nothing to do with performance... Ensuring that you initialize your fields explicitly is a compile time check. Having implicit defaults is stupid. Why is zero automatically a good value for an integer? Why not the minimum value or the maximum value?