# What are the default values in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I see that new `Arrays` are always initialised with default values. For example, an int array will have all its elements initialised as `0` initially. For example:

```java
int myArray = new int[7];
System.out.println(myArray[3]); // 0
```

I wanted to ask how arrays of other types (primitives & non-primitives) are initialised and what  values do their elements hold initially?

Answer (score -1):

All the arrays of *non-primitives* types would have their elements initialised as `null`. And the arrays of *primitive* types will be initialised as follows:

- Arrays of type `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long` will have elements initialised as `0`
- Arrays of type `float`, `double` will have elements initialised as `0.0`
- Arrays of type `boolean` will have elements initialised as `false`
- Arrays of type `object` will have elements initialised as `null`
- Arrays of type `char` will have elements initialised as '\u0000' which is a *null character*.

Comment: You forgot `char`.

Comment: Thank you for trying to cover questions and answers that don't exist already on Stack Overflow, but please make sure they truly don't exist. ([What is the default initialization of an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3426843/12323248))